# kafka - can python program connect to Kafka outside hadoop cluster?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I would like to write a python program which reads a file and writes the data to Kafka as a producer. Kafka is setup in the Hadoop cluster and Python will be running outside Hadoop cluster.

is it possible to connect from outside? 
do i need to install Kafka libraries for python? how do I need to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to learn more about Kafka is to use http://landoop.com/docs/lenses/developers

You will need to run 1 docker - to bring up everything locally and then developer a Python app, using the appropriate Kafka libs that connect to Kafka via the Kafka APIs and produce messages to it

Once you've built your app - you can then package it and run it against your your Hadoop's Kafka brokers

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to make my career in kafka & pyspark. I do have a VM & just now installed kafka libraries. Now, i will write a small python program which reads a file & publish it to kafka. Again thank you.

Comment: Please disclose any [affiliations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and do not use the site as a way to promote your site through posting. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to connect from outside?

Depends on the firewall rules, but yes, it is possible

> do i need to install Kafka libraries for python? how do I need to install?

Yes. There are several Python libraries for Kafka. [`pip install kafka-python`, for example.](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)